# Trying to understand cx_Oracle`s LOB object

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I have a database class in python which I use to query the database.

```
class Database():
  def __init__(self, user, password, host, port, service_name, mode, *args):
    #mode should be 0 if not cx_Oracle.SYSDBA
    self.user = user
    self.password = password
    self.host = host
    self.port = port
    self.user = user
    self.service_name = service_name
    self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    self.mode = 0
    self.connection = None
    self.connect_string = self.user + '/' + self.password + '@' + dsn
    try:
      self.connection = cx_Oracle.connect(self.connect_string, mode=self.mode, threaded=True)
      self.connection.stmtcachesize = 1000
      self.connection.client_identifier = 'my_app_scheduler'
      self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
      self.cursor.arraysize = 10000
      self.idVar = self.cursor.var(cx_Oracle.NUMBER)
    except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError, exc:
      error, = exc
      self.logger.exception('Exception occured while trying to create database object : %s', error.message)
      raise exc

  def query(self, q):
    try:
      self.cursor.execute(q)
      return self.cursor.fetchall(), self.cursor.rowcount
    except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError, exc:
      raise exc
```

And this is the code to manipulate the fetched data and convert it.

```
output, rowcount = db_run_query.query(sql_text)
      #self.logger.debug('output : %s, type : %s', output, type(output))
      end_time=time.time()
      time_taken=end_time - start_time
      self.logger.debug('Rowcount : %s, time_taken : %s', rowcount, time_taken)
      column_name = [d[0] for d in db_run_query.cursor.description]
      result = [dict(zip(column_name, row)) for row in output]
      #Convert everything to string : Eg: datetime
      try:
        for each_dict in result:
          for key in each_dict:
            if isinstance(each_dict[key], cx_Oracle.LOB):
              self.logger.debug('%s', each_dict[key].size())
              each_dict[key]=each_dict[key].read()
              #self.logger.debug('%s %s %s %s %s %s %s', key, each_dict, type(key), type(each_dict[key]), type(each_dict), temp_each_dict, type(temp_each_dict))
            else:
              each_dict[key]=str(each_dict[key])
      except Exception as e:
        self.logger.debug(e)
```

So without `self.cursor.arraysize = 10000`

and for a query like `select clob_value from table` it was able to fetch the data and logged Rowcount : 4901, time_taken : 0.196296930313 but was giving me an error like

```
LOB variable no longer valid after subsequent fetch
```

but when I mention the arraysize parameter the error goes away. `( Is arraysize only for lob columns coz it works fine for select other_column from table where rownum<20000  <- other_column in varchar)`
Why does that happen?

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out CLOBs and `fetchall` [don't place nice together](https://github.com/Bluehorn/cx_Oracle/blob/master/doc/lob.rst):

```
Internally, Oracle uses LOB locators which are allocated based on the
cursor array size. Thus, it is important that the data in the LOB
object be manipulated before another internal fetch takes place. The
safest way to do this is to use the cursor as an iterator. In
particular, do not use the fetchall() method.
```

Avoiding `cursor.fetchall()` and using it like an iterator (e.g. `for row in cursor: ...`) and i was able to get around this problem.